# Having trouble with what to write as my return?

Tags: java

I'm writing a caesar encryption method. For every character of the original string, I want my method to shift the character by three. For example, 'A' shifted to 'D' and so forth. Now I want to combine all the shifted characters in a single string (encrypted message) and return it.

How do I write statements to combine the characters and then return it.

Comment: If you remove the code the answer doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate all the characters to form a string. Then return the string.

At first you declare a String object:

```
String result ="";
```

Inside the for loop, after the if-else statement, you add the shifted character to your resultant string:

```
result = result + t;
```

Then in the end (outside for loop) you return the resultant string:

```
return result;
```

And if you wanna use StringBuilder:

1. Create a StringBuilder object:

   `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`
2. Append character:

   `builder.append('a');` or

   `char t = 'b';
    builder.append(t);`
3. Convert to String and return:

   `return builder.toString();`

Comment: Note that you should use `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings inside a loop to avoid performance penalty of creating many instances of String.

Comment: How do I concatenate all my characters if I have no limit for the length of the string?

Comment: You are running the loop for the length of the original message. It will iterate and concatenate all the characters.
@JiriTousek: Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Osmani I tried it all and it told me it couldn't find the variable t and when I put my return statement outside of the loop it tells me it's an "illegal start of type"

Comment: You have to declare the String result in the beginning before the for loop. I  will edit the answer to make more sense.

Comment: All I had to do was remove return null and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To return an encrypted message you can recursively call your own method with the message. Make sure you have a condition on when you should return `null` (or in this case your own message).
One small problem with your loop is you just shift the char `t` but not replace in to a string or make your return string. You should store your result somewhere.